# How to go back to root view controller in uisplitviewcontroller like "Settings" app in iPad?

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

In the "settings" app of iPad, if u click on "General" > "About", then click on "General" at the side. The "About" page will jump back to root view controller.

How do I achieve that in swift?

I'm currently using `self.splitViewController?.showDetailViewController` on click at "masterview"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
self.splitViewController?.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```